# Animated cube-like (only two faces) effect with CSS3

Tags: css, animation, transform

I would like to reproduce this jsfiddle I that prepared based on [this awesome tutorial](http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/) (please check [the demo](http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/)). But I don't want the keys functionality, just on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/b5rmW/5/

But that only uses 2 faces (front and back).

I tried, like this:

```
    #cube {
      position: relative;
      margin: 100px auto 0;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

      -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s linear;
      -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .face {
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      padding: 0px;
      background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
      font-size: 27px;
      line-height: 1em;
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      border-radius: 3px;
    }

    #cube .one  {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
      background:red;
    }

    #cube .two {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(150px);
      -moz-transform: translateZ(150px);
    background:gold;
    }

    #cube .three {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
    background:blue;
    }

    #cube .four {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
    background:green;
    }

    #cube .five {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
    background:orange;
    }

    #cube .six {
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(150px);
      -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(150px);
    }
#cube:hover{
   transform:rotateY(90deg); 

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5XTeU/1/

But the effect seems not to be the same.

What do you think is the minimum divs needed to achieve this first fiddle??

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sort of doubting my answer now, since there are actually 2 jsFiddle demos in the question. The first fiddle does not have a _front_ and _back_, it's actually a _front_ and _side_. So which fiddle do you want help with? Also, do you want a _front_ and _back_ rotating?

Comment: The second one. Is my fail in removing undesired divs from the fiddle 1 (wich works fine), So I need help with the second fiddle; Wich only uses 2 faces. thanks!

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. So which 2 faces should it be? Do you want to rotate 2 faces that are connected - a _front_ and a _side_ - or the _front_ and _back_ which are not connected?

Comment: I have updated my answer for _front_ and _side_ face rotation which matches the other demo fiddle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** So a slight misunderstanding on which faces need to exist… so this update is for a *front* and *side* face rotation.

However, in the original answer below, points 1) and 2) are still valid problems with the code. Points 3) and 4) no longer apply since they were concerned with the *back* face. The remaining CSS rules can be removed. You could also pull in the *perspective* wrapper to give the cube a "less flat" look - see [**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3S37r/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="experiment">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="face front">
            front face
        </div>
        <div class="face side">
            side face
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#experiment {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;

    -moz-perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
}

.cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.cube .front {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(150px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(150px);
    background-color:red;
}

.cube .side {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
    background-color:orange;
}

.cube:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);     
}
```

---

**Original Answer**

There are 4 problems with the demo code, so let's look at them individually and see what the solution to each one is:

1) the HTML has a typo on class for the *front* face - it is missing an `r`

`<div class="face font">` instead of `<div class="face front">`

2) For Webkit browsers you need to use the prefixed property for `transform`

`-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);` instead of `transform:rotateY(90deg);`

3) The *back* face you have chosen is the wrong face. You have repurposed the *left* face by accident. The *front* face  is correct, which is a `<div>` translated `150px` outwards. So the corresponding *back* face should be the one translated `-150px` inwards. However, if we just do that, the position would be correct but when rotated around the centre of the cube the back face would end up backwards. So the correct *back* face is the one that is initially rotated by 180° around the `Y` axis. However, by rotating around the `Y` axis the translation along `Z` still needs to be `+150px` and not `-150px`.

```
.cube .back{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
   background:orange;
}
```

4) The rotation to get the *back* face into the position where the *front* starts should be a rotation of 180° and not 90°

```
.cube:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Putting all those changes together gives [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3S37r/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="cube">
    <div class="face front">
        front face
    </div>
    <div class="face back">
        back face
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.cube .front {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(150px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(150px);
    background-color: red;
}

.cube .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
    background:orange;
}

.cube:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! What an elaborated answer and the solution is better (tiny 3d effect you added) than the one I was asking for!

Comment: (it doesn't seem to work in FF but I guess that when I convert it to compas mixins it will)

Comment: Happy to help! Which part is not working in FF? I can't test FF right now but can see what I can do tomorrow.

Comment: @andyb: you seem to know a lot about css3-stuff, do you know if it's possible to add shadows to the faces that are not parallel to the viewer? Check out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903674/css3-3d-box-with-shadows

Comment: Enjoy your new badge ;) just a note, your hover will fail in firefox

Comment: Thanks for the badge and comment @Mr.Alien. I have added the `-moz-transform` but I cannot test on Firefox at the moment. I don't know how you manage to spend so much time on SO but I see you all the time! You have a very impressive profile :-)

Comment: @andyb I would recommend you to add standard properties as well, firefox supports standard ones, and haha thanks for the nice words :) ypu have a pretty good profile too...