# CSS3 3D Box With Shadows

Tags: css, rotation, shadow

I'm making a notification system. I want this notification to show up like a box that turns, somewhat like some notifications in iOS that the top of the screen rotates like a cube.

Now, the front and back of the cube should be transparant/same color as background. When it turns, a shadow should fall over the sides that are not parallel to the front of the viewer, as if there is a lamp shining on the box. Can this be done?

**To make more clear:** Since the front & back of the box are the same as the background-color, when turning the box it wouldn't seem like a box turning but rather a slice of paper that rotates into place. So what I want is that faces of the cube get a shadow to it depending on their angle as opposed to the viewer.

For example, once the front-face (which you can't really see since it's the same color as the background-color) is rotated 1 degree, it should get a little darker/lighter. Another degree, a little more. So that the true color of the face is only shown when it's directly parallel to the user. This will create the illusion of there being a box, rather than a sliver of paper.

I'm using this tutorial on the cube: http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BqJMW/3/

Another issue is that currently the text seems a bit stretched, if you know what I mean. Normally the `transform: translateZ(-25px);` (see code below) on the `#cube` should solve this, but it still seems out of proportion.

## CSS

```
body {
    background: #ebebeb;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-25px);
    transform: tranlateZ(-25px);
}
#cube figure {
    margin:0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cube .front {
    background: transparant;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
    transform: translateZ(25px);
}
#cube .top {
    background: green;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}
#cube .back {
    background: transparant;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(25px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#cube.show-front {
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(-25px);
    tranform: translateZ(-25px);
}
#cube.show-top {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-25px);
    transform: translateZ(-25px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
#cube.show-back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-25px);
    transform: translateZ(-25px);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

## HTML

```
<section class="container">
  <div id="cube">
    <figure class="front">Front</figure>
    <figure class="top">Your notification</figure>
    <figure class="back">Back</figure>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the shadow part. Any chance you can either describe it differently or add a simple image showing the shadows?

Comment: @andyb: I've clarified my answer a bit. I'm no good at photoshop, else I'd make a quick mock-up. I could try and fumble something in css if it isn't clear though.

Comment: OK I understand now :-) I think I have a solution as well. Post soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the initial colour of the *notification face* to a darker version of the final color, we can use a [CSS3 transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) on the `color` attribute of that face to animate it to a lighter colour as the face is rotated.

I've added a new class with the lighter "green" that will be added/removed to/from the *notification face* and changed the initial `color` added a new transition to `#cube .top`.

I've also corrected some typos in the CSS (`tranform` → `transform`, `transparant` → `transparent`) and removed the duplicate `-webkit-transform:translateZ(-25px);` and non-prefixed version from the `.show-front|top|back` classes as they are being overridden in the same class.

Lastly, since the *notification face* is translated towards the viewer by `25px` the text looks blurry (on Chrome). This seems to go away by removing the `-webkit-perspective: 1000px;` for me. I'll leave that up to you if you want to remove it.

See the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RsXy7/) or following code:

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #ebebeb;
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-25px);
    transform: translateZ(-25px);
}
#cube figure {
    margin:0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
#cube .front {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(25px);
    transform: translateZ(25px);
}
#cube .top{
    background-color:darkgreen;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(25px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transition:background-color .5s;
}
#cube .top.show {
    background-color:green;
}
#cube .back {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX( 180deg ) translateZ(25px);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#cube.show-front{
}
#cube.show-top {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
#cube.show-back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.showfront').click(function () {
    $('.top').removeClass('show');
    $('#cube').removeClass().addClass('show-front');
});
$('.showtop').click(function () {
    $('.top').addClass('show');
    $('#cube').removeClass().addClass('show-top');
});
$('.showback').click(function(){
    $('.top').removeClass('show');
    $('#cube').removeClass().addClass('show-back');
});
```

Comment: Very neat solution! Made the `transition: transform .5s` to 1s since the cube rotates for 1s, and also implemented it for the  other faces: http://jsfiddle.net/RsXy7/1/

Comment: Yeah I was playing around with the transition times but wasn't sure if you needed them to match. It looks good with the effect applied to the other faces :-)